# Interesting question about exponential generating function of the number of partitions under a certain statistic.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs, set-partition

Find the exponential generating function of the number of partitions of $[n]$ ( according to) under the statistic of the number of blocks that contain an even number of elements (a block $K$ such that $|K|$ is even).

Then find the expectation (average) of blocks with even number of elements.

There are many questions with similar ideas, but are different.

So,  I said

For $n=1$ we have the partition: $\{\{1\}\}$

For $n=2$ we have $\{\{1,2\}\} , \{\{1\},\{2\}\}$

For $n=3$ we have these partitions:
$$\{ \{ 1,2,3 \} \}, \{\{1,2\}, \{ 3 \}\} ,  \{ \{ 1,3 \},\{ 2 \} \} , \{ \{2,3\},\{1\}\}, \{\{ 1 \}, \{ 2 \}, \{3 \} \}$$

If $x$ counts a length of a single number then:

$A_1(x)=x$ ,
$A_2(x)=2x^2/2!$ ,
$A_3(x)=5x^3/3!$

Now let $q$ counts the number of blocks with even number of elements.

Then,

$A_1(q,x)=x$

$A_2(q,x)= \frac{x^2}{2
!}(q+1)$

$A_3(q,x)=\frac{x^3}{3!} (3q+2)$

I was not able to find the recurrence relation for $A_n(q)$ ($A_0(q)=1$) in order to find the exponential generating function.

Can you provide me any kind of support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want $$A_n(q)=\sum _{\pi \vdash [n]}q^{ev(\pi)},$$
where $ev(\pi):=\text{number of even blocks in }\pi.$

Well, suppose you know $A_n,$ then you want to create all blocks with $n+1$ elements. So you want to choose the elements that are going to be in the block of $n+1.$ This corresponds, without the polynomials to the recursion of Bell numbers $$B_{n+1}=\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}B_{n-i}.$$
Now, taking care of the polynomial, notice that there are two cases. Either we place $n+1$ in a block with even elements or in an odd one. If we do place it with odd elements we are forming one even block per partition on $B_{n-i}.$ So you have that
$$A_{n+1}(q)=q\sum _{i\text{ odd}}\binom{n}{i}A_{n-i}(q)+\sum _{i\text{ even }}\binom{n}{i}A_{n-i}(q).$$
Sage obtains the following polynomials for $n$ up to 10:

```
x |--> 1
x |--> x + 1
x |--> 3*x + 2
x |--> 3*x^2 + 7*x + 5
x |--> 15*x^2 + 25*x + 12
x |--> 15*x^3 + 60*x^2 + 91*x + 37
x |--> 105*x^3 + 315*x^2 + 329*x + 128
x |--> 105*x^4 + 630*x^3 + 1533*x^2 + 1415*x + 457
x |--> 945*x^4 + 4410*x^3 + 7623*x^2 + 6297*x + 1872
```

Comment: Thanks, I need to know the $A_n(q)$ for computing the exponential g.f for the given problem then its statistic. I'm not sure if it is actually what i needed though it makes, sense, i chose x to count a length of a number (is that fine?) , in your approch assuming that we know $A_n$ then the additional number has many options to join a block, it can also be in a singular  block  (not specifically joining the previous blocks we know for $A_n$), I tried to substitute in your equation but is i goes from 0 to n ? @Phicar

Comment: Yes, $n$ goes from $0$ to $n.$ My guess is that after you have this recursion, it should be pretty similar to the way you find the exp. generating function for Bell numbers.

Comment: Hey @Phicar, i did check the formula, it was alright:)! For simplicity I did use the formula $A_n$ Then I multiplied it by x^{n-1} and divided it by $(n-1)!$ and summing over $n≥1$....in the end got $\frac{d/dx A(x,q)}{A(x,q)}= cosh(x)q+sinh(x)$ , from there I'm not sure how to finish it. Since my functions are both in terms of q (not A(q,1) as in bell numbers)..

Comment: @user726608 Integrate over $x$  are you sure the $q$ is not in the sinh? When you solve the equation you should get $e^{q*(cosh-1)+sinh}.$ Notice that this makes sense in the symbolic calculus. cosh controls the even blocks and sinh controls the odd ones.

Comment: Right it was a typo, got $A(q,x)= e^{(qcoshx+sinhx)+C(q)}$ where $C(q)$ is a constant (in terms of q as we integrate over x), then substitute $A(0,q)=1$  so $C=-q$ , so we're done right @Phicar